# Jquery - Get data from mysql query

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Ok, so I'm not 100% that this is the best way to achieve what I want, but here goes.

I have some PHP code to process an SQL query, and I'm looking to pass it in the SQL value with an AJAX request. Initially I was doing all of this in PHP, i.e. I had a PHP function called 'query' which would execute an SQL command that I passed into it. This works great and I can work with the array, however I want to do more with the results and feel the need for javascript. So, to execute the PHP code I'm trying to create an AJAX request and for now just output the results.

Here's my PHP which lives in query.php

```
<?php
    static $handle;
    if (!isset($handle))
    {
        try
        {
            $handle = new PDO("mysql:dbname=" . DATABASE . ";host=" . SERVER, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
            $handle->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false); 
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            trigger_error($e->getMessage(), E_USER_ERROR);
            exit;
        }
    }

    $statement = $handle->prepare($sql);
    if ($statement === false)
    {
        exit;
    }

    $results = $statement->execute($parameters);

    if ($results !== false)
    {
        $array = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        echo json_encode($array);
    }
    else
    {
        // return false;    do nothing for now
    }
?>
```

And here is the basic JS function to process the AJAX request:

```
function query (sql) {
  $.ajax({                                      
    url: 'query.php',                        
    data: { sql: sql },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data)          
    {
        console.log(data);
    } 
  });
}
```

When I pass it a simply SQL query to test it out, I simply dont get anything in the console.

Any clues as to what I'm doing wrong or tips for a better approach?

Comment: What SQL are you sending? It does seem a bit odd that you'd be sending SQL directly from the web app, rather than abstracting it away, but you may have your reasons (can't vote on the approach without knowing more).

Comment: a simple string to test like "SELECT * FROM tbl_Contact WHERE ID = '20'"

Comment: And if you run that directly in a mysql client, it returns results?

Comment: yeah, works fine when I run it in my php function, the table exists, the ID exists, everything works, just not as above..?

Comment: And when you go to query.php directly, do you get an empty page?

Comment: where is the $sql variable initialized? maybe you want to do something like $sql = $_POST["sql"] before using it?

Comment: @james Ah no! I was getting a message telling me that the file I was including to include my database username password etc also started sessions and it was saying: Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent ... So removed that and now, although for some reason I'm getting a blank result in the console the console is logging something.... I' think i'm on the right track so thanks!!

Comment: hmm actually console logs blank when i change the dataType to html. Logging json doesnt give anything still..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cant comment, so i write an answer:

Do you setting `$sql` from `$_GET`?
Try this:

```
function query (sql) {
  $.post('query.php', { sql: sql }, function(data){
        console.log(data);
  }, 'json');
}
```

and in query.php:

```
<?php
  $sql = isset($_POST['sql']) ? $_POST['sql'] : '';
  ...
```